# Flutter - Padding using empty Containers?

Tags: flutter

I have a column that stretches from the top of my screen to the bottom, inside that column are two rows each with three buttons.

What's the best/proper way to adjust the vertical spacing between these two rows?

Currently I'm using Expanded's with an empty child container to add gaps between children of the column, so I have a 10% 'gap' between the top of the page and the first row and another 10% 'gap' between the two rows

This doesn't feel quite right and I seem to be limited to XX% amounts of padding, I want to try and avoid specific pixel amounts so the layout remains consistent regardless of screen size

```
  Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(flex: 1, child:Container()),
      Expanded(flex: 3, child:
          Row(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: _navButton(Icons.person, "User", ()=>print("User"))),
            Expanded(child: _navButton(Icons.insert_drive_file, "Formulation", ()=>print("Formulation"),)),
            Expanded(child: _navButton(Icons.lightbulb_outline, "Devices", ()=>print("Devices"),)),
          ],)),
      Expanded(flex: 1, child:Container()),
      Expanded(flex: 3, child:
        Row(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(flex: 3, child: _navButton(Icons.settings, "Settings", ()=>print("Settings"), iconColour: Colors.blueGrey)),
          Expanded(flex: 3, child: _navButton(Icons.camera_alt, "Photos", ()=>print("Photos"),)),
          Expanded(flex: 3, child: _navButton(Icons.cancel, "Exit", ()=>print("Exit"), iconColour: Colors.redAccent)),
        ],
      )),
    ],
  )
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of `Expanded`, you can use `Spacer`. It is the same as an `Expanded` with an empty `Container`.

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Begin'),
    Spacer(), // Defaults to a flex of one.
    Text('Middle'),
    // Gives twice the space between Middle and End than Begin and Middle.
    Spacer(flex: 2),
    Text('End'),
  ],
)
```

You can also use a `SizedBox` for spacing in DIP:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Begin'),
    const SizedBox(width: 42),
    Text('Middle'),
  ],
)
```

Another one is `Flexible`, which is similar to `Expanded` but works with min/max size:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Begin'),
    Flexible(
      child: ConstrainedBox(constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 100.0)),
    ),
    Text('Middle'),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Sorry, DIP: Density Independent Pixel. It's the unit of measure Flutter uses

Comment: Many thanks for this - `spacer` looks like the neater option - regarding flex, is `flex: 1` equivalent to 10% of the space? And is there anyway to go smaller? `flex: 0.5`?

Comment: @user6635665 `flex` is not related to %. Its behavior is the same as with CSS flex

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sense - not sure where I picked up the % idea

Answer (score 0):

```
extension EmptyPadding on num {
SizedBox get ph => SizedBox(height: toDouble());

SizedBox get pw => SizedBox(width: toDouble());
}
```

Simply use this extension for empty padding line number 20

[image: See line number 20]